# PHP mysql dynamic table (attendance sheet)

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I have 3 tables in my database:

- students
- courses
- attendance

The first 2 tables have 2 fields (id, name) and the third has: corseID, studID, attDate and attStatus where attStatus is either present or absent

What I need is this: a dynamic table with the following properties :

- the first column should be titled "Name" populated with student names from the student's table(done)
- the first row should be populated with the dates from the attDate field in the attendance table (done)
- the rest of the cells in between the above mentioned column and  row should have the attendance status pulled from the attStatus field in the attendance table giving the student name and attendance date

Please provide a walk-through of how to tackle this problem (the more details, the better).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following SQL query to get **ALL** records:

```
SELECT
s.id Student_ID,
s.name Student_Name,
c.name Course_Name,
a.attStatus Attendance_Status,
a.attDate Attendance_Date
FROM students s
INNER JOIN attendance a ON (s.id=a.studID)
INNER JOIN courses c ON (a.courseID=c.id)
ORDER BY a.attDate ASC
```

**Edit**:

You didn't say that whether a student can attend multiple courses per day, so I assume it can.

On PHP side, do things like:

```
$dates=array();
$students=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 if(!in_array($dates[$row["Attendance_Date"]])) $dates[]=$row["Attendance_Date"];
 if(empty($students[$row["Student_ID"]]))
   $students[$row["Student_ID"]]=array("name"=>$row["Student_Name"]);
 if(empty($students[$row["Student_ID"]][$row["Attendance_Date"]])
   $students[$row["Student_ID"]][$row["Attendance_Date"]]=array();
 $students[$row["Student_ID"]][$row["Attendance_Date"]][$row["Course_Name"]]=$row["Attendance_Status"];
}
```

So when the loop finishes, you can ended up with such `$students` array:

```
Array(2) =>
{
  123 =>
   {
     "name"=>"Einstein",
     "2012-08-01"=>
      {
        "Math"=>"present",
        "Phys"=>"absent"
      }
     "2012-08-02"=>
      {
        "Liter"=>"absent",
        "Music"=>"present"
      }
   }
  456 =>
   {
     "name"=>"Heisenberg",
     "2012-08-01"=>
      {
        "Math"=>"absent",
        "Phys"=>"present"
      }
   }
}
```

And with all the dates in `$dates` array. Then you can `foreach` the `$dates` array to draw the first row, and then `foreach($students){foreach($dates){}}` to draw every row.

Comment: this does get me the results i want but my issue is how do i get them displayed as outlined before